# background image repeat effect in cocos creater

Tags: cocoscreator

How can background image be set in repeat effect in cocos creater ?

If character runs, back image should be flow backwards, but I want to background repeatedly continuously repeated by using one device size image file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by using two background images, placed one after the other, with anchors 0,0, size assumed to be same as canvas size (Images not placed inside the canvas). This script applied to both images can achieve that effect, in simplest form.

```js
cc.Class({
    extends: cc.Component,

    properties: {
        // speed of scrolling
        speed: 0,
        // reset to position
        bgwidth: 0
    },

    // use this for initialization
    onLoad: function () {
    },

    // called every frame, uncomment this function to activate update callback
    update: function (dt) {
        var x = this.node.x;
        x -= this.speed * dt;
        if (x <= -this.bgwidth) {
            x += this.bgwidth*2;
        }
        this.node.x = x;
    },
});
```